# How to add second HDD in Ubuntu without data loss that was used in Windows with partition?

Tags: partitioning, mount, hard-drive

I installed ubuntu replacing my windows 7. I had SSD and HDD in windows. SSD was Windows now its replaced with Ubuntu os.I need to recover and add my HDD that was used in windows. I need to add without data loss. HDD was with 3 partition while used in windows.Now I need to recover all the data and add as second HDD in ubuntu, how to do that?

Comment: So you have 3 partitions on your HDD, containing data, and you want to add them to existing Ubuntu installation? Or has the data been deleted from your HDD - because you use the word "recover"?

Comment: You need the (slow) `ntfs-3G`driver, so that linux can read the hard disk. But you shouldn't use it as permanent drive - save your data and reformat it to ext4. Add the harddrive boils down to a "mount". Check "How to mount a drive in linux" in your favorite search engine

Comment: @kanehekili NTFS driver is integrated in recent kernels by default, no need for ntfs-3g anymore. And with the kernel driver, it is absolutely OK to use NTFS formatted drive for data, no need to reformat to ext4.

Comment: Thanks for clearing this up. I haven't used windows/ntfs for the last 10 years, but at that time NTFS had no journaling,but file fragmentation and was up to 30% slower than ext4... But times are changing I guess.

Comment: See at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AutomaticallyMountPartitions

Comment: Hi Raj, yes I have 3 partitions on my HDD(2nd one) containing data and I wan to add them to existing ubuntu os.